# What is the Signature of LocalTime datatype in Java to create objects with it ? int/string cannot be applied to LocalTime Error

Tags: java, localtime

This is in my constructor in class Office.

```
  public Office(String name, String location, LocalTime openingTime, LocalTime closingTime) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.openingTime = openingTime;
        this.closingTime = closingTime;
    }
```

Now, I want to create an object of Class Office with LocalTime being one of the attributes. However I'm unable to pass the values for Localtime while creating the object. I'm trying

```
   Office office1=new Office("Company Name","Chennai",10:30,6:30);
   //Or this
   Office office1=new Office("Company Name","Chennai",10,6);
   //Or this
   Office office1=new Office("Company Name","Chennai",'10:30','6:30');
   //Or this
   Office office1=new Office("Company Name","Chennai","10:30","6:30");
```

None of these is working so far. It is not matching with the signature of the data type LocalTime. Would appreciate the solution to this.

Comment: The solution is to create instances of `LocalTime` for the arguments. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) for available static factory methods (e.g., the `of(...)` methods, or the `parse(...)` methods, though the former seems more appropriate for your use case). As an example, `LocalTime.of(10, 30)` would give you a `LocalTime` instance for 10:30 AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can more briefly define your class as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16+. A record is appropriate if the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
public record Office ( String name, String location, LocalTime openingTime, LocalTime closingTime ) {}
```

Instantiate. Pay attention to 24-hour clock.

```
Office o = new Office ( "Acme Corp." , "Chennai" , LocalTime.parse( "10:30" ) , LocalTime.of( 18 , 30 ) ) ;
```

---

You obviously have yet to master the basics of the Java language. Please **study your textbook and other resources before posting** here. Oracle provides the [*Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) free of cost.